# Deciding between lossless and lossy compression?

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, compression

I have a bunch of images I need to store in memory, but they're taking up quite a bit of room, which I want to reduce. They're currently being stored as bitmaps, hence the large amount of required space.

I want to instead store them in some sort of compressed format. I want to store it either as a JPEG or a PNG. For images that don't contain any fine details (i.e. just rough shapes, basic colours), I want to store these as JPEGs since, the lossy behaviour of the format won't make too much of a difference because there isn't a lot of detailed information in the first place. However, for images that contain fine details (i.e text, subtle colours and small detailed shapes/textures), I want to store these as PNGs, because I don't want the fine details to be lost.

I've done a fair bit of research but wasn't able to find answers to my questions. Could someone help me out with these please?

a) Does this seem like a reasonable approach? I don't have a lot of experience with compression.

b) To decide, whether to store it as a PNG or a JPEG, I was thinking I could calculate the entropy of the image, and then threshold it. I'm hoping that "low entropy images" would correspond to images without fine details, while "high entropy images" would contain text and fine details. Is my intuition correct?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll probably get better answers at http://dsp.stackexchange.com  But, first check that this will be on-topic there.  Then delete this version and post if appropriate.  Here your question borders on off-topicality, it's kinda broad and kinda opinion-seeking.

Comment: Or you could use FLIF for everything

Comment: @Harold But FLIF is lossless. I want to be able to take advantage of lossy techniques whenever I can. Don't know much about FLIF but I doubt a lossless technique could ever hold its own against a lossy one in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: Well look at the comparison chart, but there's also lossy FLIF.

Comment: Why do you need to store these images in memory? If you need to manipulate them, you'll need the uncompressed versions anyway. If you just need to access them frequently, you may want to look at a memory cache solution with a disk fallback for the ones that were accessed the longest time ago.

Comment: What sort of images are they? Photographs typically don't compress all that well with PNG. Note also that for JPEG you can usually specify the level of compression you want to some degree (and obviously, greater compression means more distortion).

Comment: You should do some size comparisons using your data. It's quite possible that there is little difference in compression ratio with simple images. That is, low entropy images should compress quite well even with a lossless algorithm.